# How to view Shelved P4 Changes?

Tags: perforce, shelve

One of our team member (located in different region) has shelved changes in P4 with changelist 1234.

Now, if I want to see what files are modified snf what are the changes, how can I do this?

What is the P4 command that I should use to see the changes made by our team member?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`p4 describe -S 1234` should to the trick, see [the documentation on describe](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/describe.html).

To see the file content you would *unshelve* the files into your workspace (assuming you have a workspace for the same project your colleague is working on).

Create a new (empty) changelist with `p4 change` (results in e.g. 2345), then use `p4 unshelve` ([docu](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/unshelve.html)) to get the modified files to your workspace:

```
p4 unshelve -s 1234 -c 2345
```

If you don't want the modified files in your workspace any longer, you can `p4 revert -c 2345` them.

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to download those files (which have shelved changes in my P4 workspace, what would be the command?

Comment: You could just use P4V for that

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Quite annoying that a new argument is necessary to view shelved changes. </rant>

Comment: When I enter `p4 revert -c 2345` I get **Missing/wrong number of arguments.** The "files" argument is mandatory, although I would expect it to default to _all_ the files in the changelist.

Comment: please, tell me if I wrong: there is a problem with 'p4 describe -S 1234' - it shows content only for modified files, but not newly added. But anyway THANK YOU @jhwist

Comment: p4 describe -S -du3 -O 1234 will Nice diff with description

Comment: If you don't like the view, try 
`p4 describe -du -S 1234  | colordiff | less`, trust me you will like this, which looks similar to git diff

Answer (score 34):

Using the GUI, go to Pending and remove all filters except by user, where you will put the other developer's ID. From there you should be able to see her Changelists, including the ones having shelved files. Right click on the Shelved Files icon and select Unshelve. You will have to have a workspace active that includes the files that you are trying to unshelve.

Comment: It is actually easier to hit Ctrl-G and enter the changelist number

Comment: After going to Pending and searching for the person's username, I added the Date column and sorted by most recent to see all of their shelves.

Answer (score 13):

Using UI client, press Ctrl+G. Dialog window is appears. Select Changelist in combobox and input number of changelist.

Answer (score 11):

Let's assume that changelist 123456 is the shelved changelist in question. As a previous answer mentioned, the way to list the files are associated with that changelist is via the `p4 describe -s <changelist>` command.  Like so:

```
$ p4 describe -s 123456
Change 123456 by john.doe@JohnsBranch on 2013/10/24 15:38:10 *pending*

    [Shelving my changes for Jane.]
    Fix memory corruption caused by uninitialized pointer.

Affected files ...

... //depot/branches/JohnsBranch/kernel/vm/pageutils.c#1 edit
```

Once you know the file(s) in question, there are a couple of ways to diff the files without a corresponding workspace.  Method #1 is to use `p4 print`:

```
$ p4 print -q //depot/branches/JohnsBranch/kernel/vm/pageutils.c#1       > /tmp/old
$ p4 print -q //depot/branches/JohnsBranch/kernel/vm/pageutils.c@=123456 > /tmp/new
$ diff /tmp/old /tmp/new    # Or use kdiff3, tkdiff, etc.
          ...
  <diff output here>
```

The other method is to use `p4 diff2`:

```
$ p4 diff2 //depot/branches/JohnsBranch/kernel/vm/pageutils.c#1 //depot/branches/JohnsBranch/kernel/vm/pageutils.c@=123456
          ...
  <diff output here based on Perforce server's diff algorithm>
```

Both methods can be easily incorporated into the scripting language of choice.

Comment: The `p4 print` / `p4 diff2` method is especially useful when you cannot unshelve the file locally due to it being locked.

Comment: thanks for point out `@=` rather than `@` to get shelved file

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to see the actual content of the files, you could use:

```
p4 print <file>@=<shelved_change>
```

The @= means to look at the shelved change, where as @ means to look at the change.

Comment: plus1 Last line really helps.

Comment: ++ :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 6):

jhwist's solution is good if you want to see the files' diffs.

If you want to see just the shelved files, use `p4 describe -sS 1234`.

The lower case `s` restricts the output from including file diffs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see **only the list of files** inside a ChangeList (whether it's a shelve, pending or submitted CL), without extra data, grep the result:

```
p4 describe -S 12345 | grep -oP '(?=//).*(?=#)'
```

Comment: `p4 describe -sS` does the job with a little less hassle. The lower case `s` restricts the diffs  from being displayed.

Comment: -s still shows the changelist description.  This answer is the best given "if you want to see **only the list of files**"

Comment: With this method you still need to use -sS, because otherwise each file will appear twice in the output

Answer (score 2):

In P4V UI, select

```
Search - > Go To
```

then choose type of changelist (in your case 'Pending changelist'), enter changelist number and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
p4 -ztag describe <changeno>
```

The description contains a string called '... shelved' if it is shelved.